# how to derive the formula of Jacobi theta function which is below

Tags: theta-functions

What is the derivative of Jacobi theta function which is:
$$\Theta_3(z;\tau)= \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \exp(i\pi\tau n^2)\exp(2ni z)$$
and find its zeros.

Comment: See [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiThetaFunctions.html).

Comment: And [here](http://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticFunctions/EllipticTheta3/)